# Как седлать выбранные пункты в select не подсвеченными?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы выбранный пункт в select не выделялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может css свойством [OutlineStyle](http://www.weblabla.ru/reference/css/pr_outline-style.html) или псевдоэлементом [::selection](http://www.gargona.com/art/selection.php)?
Был уже похожий вопрос про Cromium но не могу его найти... Найду - скажу :)

Comment: хорошо. посмотрим и попробуем

Answer (score 0):

Аттрибут "disabled"

```
<select name="hero[]">
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена" disabled>Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: мне нужно их выбирать, но подсветка не должна включаться.

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, как так? Опишите задачу подробней.
Как написали 

>выбранный пункт в select не выделялся

так и понял